# Understanding the superior method introduced by Crockford

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In the functional inheritance pattern, Crockford introduces a new `superior` method via:

```
Object.method('superior', function (name) {
    var that = this,
    method = that[name];
    return function () {
        return method.apply(that, arguments);
    };
});
```

Where `method` is :

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

**Example:**

```
var coolcat = function (spec) {
    var that = cat(spec),
        super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
    that.get_name = function (n) {
        return 'like ' + super_get_name() + ' baby';
    };
    return that;
};
```

My question is Why don't just assign `that.get_name` to `super_get_name`  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"My question is Why don't just assign `that.get_name` to `super_get_name`?"*

Because the way the `get_name` method has its `this` value set to the `that` object is by invoking it as:

```
that.get_name();
```

When a function is invoked as the method of an object, the object becomes the value of `this` in that invocation of the function.

If you had done this instead:

```
var super_get_name = that.get_name;

super_get_name();
```

Now you're invoking a detached function, so it doesn't know what its `this` value should be, and so it uses the default, which is usually the `window` object.

---

I don't like the solution that crockford shows at all. Typically, in that situation, you'd simply make a new function right there instead of relying on extensions to `Object.prototype` to do it for you. *(Extending `Object.prototype` is very ugly IMO.)*

```
var coolcat = function (spec) {
    var that = cat(spec),
        _original_get_name = that.get_name,
        super_get_name = function() {
                             return _original_get_name.apply(that, arguments);
                         };

    that.get_name = function (n) {
        return 'like ' + super_get_name() + ' baby';
    };
    return that;
};
```

---

Or in modern implementations, you'd use `Function.prototype.bind` to create a new function with its `this` value bound to whatever you provided as the first argument to `.bind()`.

```
var coolcat = function (spec) {
    var that = cat(spec),
        super_get_name = that.get_name.bind(that);

    that.get_name = function (n) {
        return 'like ' + super_get_name() + ' baby';
    };
    return that;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the `bind` tip, I don't like [tag:crockford] hack too.

Answer (score 2):

In the sense of Crockford's Functional Inheritance Pattern it is completely valid to reference the base class method

```
var super_get_name = that.get_name;
```

**This is how Crockford teaches it in his [lecture JavaScript Master Class](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596809614.do) , see the part on Functional Inheritance.**

Later - the method might be overriden by the derived class - you invoke it simply

```
super_get_name();
```

Crockford's `superior` method makes no sense in the Functional Inheritance Pattern.

Because in my opinion **`this` is never needed** in a method defined by a producer function. If you use `this` in your methods you'll run in all sorts of trouble because of dynamic scoping and manipulation of `this`:

```
function mammal(spec){
    var that = {};
    that.legs = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
    that.get_name = function(){
        return spec.name + "with" + that.legs; // always use that not this
    };
    that.isProperThis = function(){
        console.log( this === that );
    };
    return that;
};
var myMammal = mammal({name: 'Herb'});
myMammal.isProperThis(); // true
myMammal.isProperThis.call(window); // false
setTimeout(myMammal.isProperThis, 1); // false
```

If you insist on using `this` in your methods you can no longer treat them as "first-class" variables in JavaScript. Instead you have to convert them to "binders" by calling `bind` as described in the first answer in this post.

Answer (score 0):

`superior` is a method defined in the prototype of the Object constructor function. It caches an object's method, so that it returns the original method even if it were changed later.

From JavaScript: The Good Parts, p.54:

> *The function will invoke the original method even if the property is changed.*

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer given by cookie monster is correct, but I would like to add clarification.

As cookie monster says, if you write

```
var super_get_name = that.get_name;
```

invocation of **super_get_name** will no longer bind any value to **this**, making it an unbound function.

However, in the case of the example Crockford gives in *The Good Parts*, it would not matter if **super_get_name** were unbound by writing it in the way you propose, because **this** would never be used in its invocation.

You would essentially end up doing the following:

```
super_get_name = function () {
    return that.says() + ' ' + spec.name +
            ' ' + that.says();
```

(where the right operand executes in the context of the function assigned to **cat**).

I assume that Crockford avoids unbound functions here to demonstrate a general principle, even though his specific example does not require binding.