# Accessing to superior methods in the functional Inheritance pattern (a counter example unexpectedly works !)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, functional-programming

In the process of understanding the functional inheritance pattern introduced by Crockford I come with this peace of code:

```
var person = function(spec) {
    var that= {};
    that.name = spec.name;
    that.job = spec.job || '';
    that.greeting = function() {
        console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.name + " and I'm a " + this.job);
    };
    return that;
};

var coder = function(spec) {
    var that = person(spec);
    that.job = "coder";
    // that.superior_greeting= that.superior('greeting');
    that.superior_greeting = that.greeting;
    that.greeting = function(){
        console.log("I write code");
    };
    return that;
};
```

Lets create`coder` instance `aCoder = coder({name: "tarrsalah"});`, calling the `greeting`  method prints `I write code` as I suspected.

**My question is**:  Why running the `superior_greeting` give me a different result (prints `Hello, I'm tarrsalah and I'm a coder`) ?

Is `superior_greeting` points to `that.greeting`, isn't modifying the `greeting` method should modify the `superior_greeting` also ?

**ps:** [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332306/understanding-the-superior-method-introduced-by-crockford).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Is `superior_greeting` points to `that.greeting`, isn't modifying the greeting method should modify the `superior_greeting` also?"*

No. The `superior_greeting` doesn't point to `greeting` in the way you seem to assume. JavaScript doesn't have pointers, though its objects (including functions) are held as a reference.

So at the moment that you do this:

```
that.superior_greeting = that.greeting;
```

...the `superior_greeting` holds a reference to the same function as `greeting`. It does *not* however hold a pointer to the `greeting` property itself.

---

So basically you didn't make a copy of the function, but you did make a copy of the reference to the same function, which exists *somewhere* in memory.

Because you don't have a pointer to the `.greeting` property, changes to that property are not visible from `.superior_greeting`.

So when you do this:

```
that.greeting = function(){
    console.log("I write code");
};
```

...you created a new function, and assigned the new reference to that new function to the `.greeting` property.

Now `.greeting` and `.superior_greeting` are holding reference to two different functions.

Comment: Nice !, can you please clarify the role of Object.superior method introduced by [tag:crockford] in his book ?

Comment: @tarrsalah: IMO, its role is to be left in a closet and forgotten... but to answer the last sentence of your other question, if you just assigned `that.get_name` to `super_get_name`, when you invoked it, the value of `this` in `get_name` would not be the `that` object, because you've detached `get_name` from `that`. What `superior` does is return a function that invokes the original method from the `that` object, so that `this` in the method will be a reference to the `that` object

Answer (score 0):

It is so because

```
that.superior_greeting = that.greeting;
```

comes before

```
that.greeting = function(){
    console.log("I write code");
};
```

`that.superior_greeting` is set to the old `person` version of it, before `coder` overwrites it.

It's like

```
that.superior_greeting = function() {
    console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.name + " and I'm a " + this.job);
};
that.greeting = function(){
    console.log("I write code");
};
```

If you reverse your two original lines, you would wind up with something different.

Comment: So assigning a function to another copy the code of the function not just a reference to it ?

Comment: Yes. It wouldn't matter if `greeting` and `superior_greeting` were functions, numbers, objects, etc. The result would be similar.

Comment: So Crock ford introduce a new function (`Object.superior`) to achieve the same result (see my previous question for the code sample) ?

Comment: @tarrsalah: No, assigning a function to another does not copy the code of the function. It copies a reference to the function. Just to be clear, objects are never copied. Only the reference to the object is copied.