# error while trying to augment the in-built types in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to augment the in-built `Number` data type of javascript using below code in script tag of my HTML page:

```
 Number.method('integer', function () {
        return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
        });
        document.writeln((-10 / 3).integer( ));
```

when I browse the page in browser then developer tools report following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Number.method is not a function
>   at test.html:10 
>   (anonymous) @ test.html:10

**Browser Information**: Google Chrome

I'm unable to identify the error in my code. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Doesn't one have to use `prototype` for the inbuilt "objects"?

Comment: I've already tried that option but then the error simply changes to - `Uncaught TypeError: Number.prototype.method is not a function`

Comment: Does this topic help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035308/add-a-rounding-method-to-number-prototype-in-javascript

Comment: I haven't actually heard of the `method` function before. I'm also not seeing any documentation on it. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to define [`method`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332306/understanding-the-superior-method-introduced-by-crockford), and use [`ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) instead of `ceiling`.

```js
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
};

Number.method('integer', function () {
  return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
});

console.log((-10 / 3).integer( ));
```

Of course, in this particular case, you could also just do `number | 0`.

Comment: Thanks. I had missed adding the `method` extension for prototype of `Function`. `ceiling` was a typographical error I believe in the book itself which I'm referring currently. Good catch!